# smslib not sending sms why?

Tags: java, sms, smslib

I am trying to send a sms with smslib but It did not send the message, can somebody guide me on this?

this is my code:

```
import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class SendMessage
{
    public void doIt() throws Exception
    {
        OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
        System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
        System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
        System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1", "COM4", 115200, "Huawei", "");
        gateway.setInbound(true);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        gateway.setSimPin("0000");
        // Explicit SMSC address set is required for some modems.
        // Below is for VODAFONE GREECE - be sure to set your own!
        gateway.setSmscNumber("+919825068000");
        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
        Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
        Service.getInstance().startService();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Modem Information:");
        System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
        System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
        System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
        System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
        System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
        System.out.println();
        // Send a message synchronously.
        OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("+524747388616", "que onda como andas!");
        Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
        System.out.println(msg);
        // Or, send out a WAP SI message.
        //OutboundWapSIMessage wapMsg = new OutboundWapSIMessage("306974000000",  new URL("http://www.smslib.org/"), "Visit SMSLib now!");
        //Service.getInstance().sendMessage(wapMsg);
        //System.out.println(wapMsg);
        // You can also queue some asynchronous messages to see how the callbacks
        // are called...
        //msg = new OutboundMessage("309999999999", "Wrong number!");
        //srv.queueMessage(msg, gateway.getGatewayId());
        //msg = new OutboundMessage("308888888888", "Wrong number!");
        //srv.queueMessage(msg, gateway.getGatewayId());
        System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
        System.in.read();
        Service.getInstance().stopService();
    }

    public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification
    {
        public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg)
        {
            System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
        try
        {
            app.doIt();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and my result:

```
Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.
SMSLib: A Java API library for sending and receiving SMS via a GSM modem or other supported gateways.
This software is distributed under the terms of the Apache v2.0 License.
Web Site: http://smslib.org
Version: 3.5.1

Modem Information:
  Manufacturer: Nokia Corporation
  Model: Nokia Internet Stick CS-10
  Serial No: 359340022861915
  SIM IMSI: ** MASKED **
  Signal Level: -53 dBm
  Battery Level: 0%


===============================================================================
<< OutboundMessage >>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gateway Id: *
 Message Id: 0
 Message UUID: e30f84ad-b083-4956-85ef-16dc89020769
 Encoding: 7-bit
 Date: Fri Mar 09 13:15:52 CST 2012
 SMSC Ref No: null
 Recipient: 524747388616
 Dispatch Date: null
 Message Status: FAILED
 Failure Cause: UNKNOWN
 Validity Period (Hours): -1
 Status Report: false
 Source / Destination Ports: -1 / -1
 Flash SMS: false
 Text: que onda como andas!
 PDU data: F17A19F47693C3A0F1BBFD0685DDE4F03C04
 Scheduled Delivery: null
===============================================================================

Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.
```

Comment: +52 seems to suggest that you're sending that message to a Mexican number. Did you change the SMSC number as the comment in the source tells you to or do you actually have a Greek Vodafone SIM card? (although +91 seems to suggest India...)

Comment: Actually I changed the smsc according a program that has my modem gsm, and the program print the name of the model and everything, just do not send the sms

Comment: Have you already successfully sent a SMS with that stick from the provided software - in case that feature may be disabled on hardware or for that SIM ?

Comment: You should enable log4j debug level for smslib. There may be a clue in logs...

Comment: I have sent messages with the nokia software, and I have tried other software gsm com demos and I have sent messages with that programs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example has extra line of code about SMSC-number. I have played with this same library and in my code there is not any SMSC - at any line of my code.

It is a suggestion, "if needed", and I certainly believe getting rid of it solves your problem. You most probably don't know what you exactly have to put on it, so better leaving it out. Then modem will not try to do this routing manually to given number but it can make it to the correct, what it knows by SIM settings on the SIM card.

Another thing I would check is that the modem really answers from COM4 port. Although now it seems to do so, because the signal strength is read. But check this always, because every startup of server can map the device to different port. I was at least having this kind of problem on Linux side.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not taken care enough (yet) to the `SerialModemGateway` constructor arguments, as you left "Huawei" as vendor whereas you use a Nokia device. That parameter is not important but the baud rate is. According to [SMSlib documentation](http://smslib.org/doc/smslib/troubleshooting/), most devices only works properly in a preset/uniq baudrate.

I propose you open other software settings to get or confirm parameters you have used:

- baud rate
- gateway SMSC number - maybe from Connection history menu according to Nokia user guide

As you get your code from an Huawei example, this example set the gateway SMSC number but this parameter is supposed to be optional for most devices, only Huawei devices may require it. Try a run without `gateway.setSmscNumber` !

I also invite you to monitor serial port traffic with [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) for instance and report it here and on SMSlib forum to get support.

Finally, you should ask SMSlib maintainer its option about your device, as it is in the [compatibility list](http://smslib.org/doc/compatibility/) (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sample code I used and tested. You can re-use it.

```
package com.stackoverflow.smstest;

import java.net.URL;

import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.OutboundWapSIMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class Main {

    public void sendMessage() throws Exception {
        OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
        System.out.println("Sample of Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
        System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
        System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com4",
                "COM4", 57600, "Huawei", "E160");
        gateway.setInbound(false);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        // gateway.setSimPin("");
        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(
                outboundNotification);
        Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
        Service.getInstance().startService();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Modem Information:");
        System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
        System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
        System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
        System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel()
                + " dBm");
        System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel()
                + "%");

        // Send a message synchronously.
        OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("+94123456789",
                "SMS test: sample message from StackOverflow");

        Service srvice = Service.getInstance();
        // Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
        System.out.println(msg);
        // Or, send out a WAP SI message.
        OutboundWapSIMessage wapMsg = new OutboundWapSIMessage("+94123456789",
                new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/"),
                "WAP test: sample message from StackOverflow!");
        // gateway.setFrom("chandpriyankara");
        // wapMsg.setFrom("chandpriyankara");
        srvice.queueMessage(wapMsg);

        Service.getInstance().stopService();
    }

    /**
     * Outbound Message informations handler
     * 
     * @author chandpriyankara
     * 
     */
    public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification {
        public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg) {
            System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: "
                    + gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main app = new Main();
        try {
            app.sendMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i try your code and i am getting this exception java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/smslib/IOutboundMessageNotification : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Comment: It seems like there is a version mismatch between some components, which I can't say exactly, but please re-check if you are using the source with same jar and dll.